# Assign options to select input through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, appendchild

I have a `Select` menu in my site, inside a table.

```
<select name = "menu" id="menu" >
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to do a JavaScript function to add another select menu with the same options in a row below of the table.
I have this:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("select");
    element1.id = "id";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
}
```

But I don't know where to add the options in here.

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: does document.createElement("option") not work? I have never used createElement for options - new Option(value,text) is what I used to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy it exactly anyway you could also use [**cloneNode()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) similar to this:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

    // Get a handle to the original select
    var orgSelect = document.getElementById("menu");

    // Make a clone, using true to indicate we also want to clone child nodes
    var dupSelect = orgSelect.cloneNode(true);

    // Change any attributes of the new select
    dupSelect.id = "id";

    // Append the new select
    cell1.appendChild(dupSelect);
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jveh2/) - Using `cloneNode()` to duplicate a `select` and `options`

---

You could then even make this a function you call, passing any relevant parameters, similar to this:

```
function createClone(elementId, newId, includeChildNodes){
    var original = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var duplicate = original.cloneNode(includeChildNodes);

    duplicate.id = newId;

    return duplicate;
}

// Call it like this
var clonedElement = createClone('menu', 'newMenu', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add options to the select element by instantiating a new [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Option) object, then passing it to the `add` method of the select element.

For example:

```
var opt = new Option("One", 1);
element1.add(opt);
```